# Is there a non-irreducible maximal subfactor other than two-sided TLJ?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

A subfactor $N \subseteq M$ is called:

- *irreducible* if $N' \cap M = \mathbb{C}$,
- *maximal* if for any intermediate subfactor $N \subseteq P \subseteq M$ then $P=\{N,M \}$.

The two-sided Temperley-Lieb-Jones (TLJ) subfactors $A_{\infty}^{(1)}$  are both maximal and **non**-irreducible.

**Question**: Is there a non-irreducible maximal subfactor other than $A_{\infty}^{(1)}$?

We assume that the non-irreducible subfactors $A_{n}^{(1)}$, with $n< \infty$, are not maximal, but if some of them are maximal, then we also exclude them in the question.

Comment: Can't you just use diagonal subfactors for n>2?

Comment: @NoahSnyder You are talking about the subfactors studied in Popa’s *Classification of amenable subfactors of type II*, Subsection 5.1.5, right? The principal graph is a Cayley graph (with multiplicities) starting from the neutral element e, so it is non-irreducible, ok. Now why should we have maximal examples with $n>2$?